# Uploadify returning $_FILES as a blank array

Tags: php, file, upload, uploadify

I'm trying to implement Uploadify into my website project, which already had a very basic file uploading system. I have uploadify configured to submit a form post, which transfers to a backend uploading php script to do the uploading and sorting of the images. However, I'm getting nothing after the upload, the $_FILES array is completely blank, and the Uploadify forums and documentation are no help at all. Here's my code:

**Front-end upload page**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js">          </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/modules/default/themes/uploadify/jquery.uploadify-  3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#file_upload').uploadify({
        'fileTypeDesc' : 'Image Files',
        'fileTypeExts' : '*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.png; *.gif',
        'method' : 'post',
        'auto' : false,
        'swf'      : '/modules/default/themes/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
        'uploader' : '/modules/default/themes/uploadify/uploadify.php',
        'onUploadComplete' : function(file, event, ID, fileObj, response, data) {
            $('#pff').submit();
        },
    });
});
```

```
//Further down the line

<form action="<?php echo $this->url('upload')?>" method="post" id="pff" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="uploadfield">
    <input type="file" name="pics" id="file_upload" />
</div>
</form>
<a href="javascript:$('#file_upload').uploadify('upload')">Upload Files</a>
```

**Back-end PHP Uploading Script Segment**

```
$errors = array();
    $uploaded = array();
    $ids = array();
    $public = $this->app->config->upload_public_default;
    $user = $this->app->userSession->user;
    $gallery = $this->app->getParamInt('gallery_id');
    $userid = $user->user_id;
    if(!empty($_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name']) && $this->app->config->allow_uploads){ 
//Code to upload the images to the user accounts 
}
```

I've been trying a variety of different things for hours, and tons of suggestions from different sites and forums. Nothing has worked or given me a hint of what to do yet. I can't seem to pass the files through to the script.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how uploadify works but pretty sure this won't work

```
<input type="file" name="pics"...
```

and

```
if(!empty($_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'])...
```

you are sending a file with name `pics` and checking it with name `Filedata` which will not work, you have to use the same name like `$_FILES['pics]`

Comment: I originally had 'pics' in there, and it still returned an empty array.

Comment: then you have an error somewhere. turn on error reporting or check your error.log

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible reason may be the file upload size limit.

First of all check the values of 'upload_max_filesize', 'post_max_size' in phpinfo

If the file size is greater than the limits set, then it may cause the $_FILES array to be blank

Reference: http://webparticles.wordpress.com/2011/08/28/uploadify-_files-array-is-empty/